# Take the average of three different text files and compile into one file

Tags: python

I have three text files within a directory that have two columns of data that are separated by a tab (`\t`).

I would like to take the average of the three numbers in the same column of three different text files. The numbers that I am concerned with are in the second column or after the tab (in a list it would be in position 1). I would then like to output a file with all of column 1 copied (they are the same text) and column 2 with the averages of the corresponding rows.

This is what I currently have: I got this code from another stack overflow question but it doesn't iterate through 3 different files.

Thank you!

```
import sys

allfiledata = []
filenames = sys.argv[1:]
for filename in filenames:
  rows = []
  with open (filename, "r") as filehandle:
    for line in filehandle:
      rows.append( line.split() )

    allfiledata.append( rows ) 


print " ".join(allfiledata[0][0])  # column headers
for i1,columns in enumerate(allfiledata[0][1:]):
  print columns[0],
  for i2,value in enumerate(columns[1:]):
    total = 0 
    for filedata in allfiledata:
      total = int(filedata[i1+1][i2+1]) + total
    print int(float(total)/len(allfiledata)+0.5), 
  print
```

My text files look like this:

file1.txt

```
AAA     4
AAB     5
AAC     0
AAD     1
```

file2.txt

```
AAA     4
AAB     5
AAC     0
AAD     1
```

file3.txt

```
AAA     4
AAB     5
AAC     0
AAD     1
```

Note: these lists go on into the thousands
I want to take the average of the numbers in three different files that look just like this and output a file with the copied first column and the averaged values of the numbers.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: No, I'm new to python programming (have some experience with java) and I work in DNA Seq, basically I already did all the program stuff, and now I have trouble trying to manipulate data when it's within a text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import glob

files = glob.glob(r'C:\files\*.txt')

d = {}
for file in files:
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            k, v = line.split()
            try:
                d[k].append(int(v))
            except KeyError:
                d[k] = [int(v)]

with open('results.txt', 'w') as f:
    for k in sorted(d.keys()):
        line = '{0}\t{1}\n'.format(k, sum(d[k])/len(d[k]))
        f.write(line)
```

**Edit:** don't forget to add `from __future__ import division` as the first code line in your script if you're not using python3 and want to get results as floats.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: This is really helpful! But another question, if the titles of my files keep changing and aren't just "file1.txt" how could I make it so I run the program and include a directory for it to find the text files inside?

Comment: You can use the [glob module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) to find filepaths matching a pattern. See updated answer.